# React Native AuthSession.startAsync does not close window after successful login

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I am building a web app with react native and expo.  I am trying to integrate with auth0 and calling the authorize API.  When I use AuthSession.startAsync it opens up a new window and redirects to auth0 fine but when I complete the login it does not redirect the user back to the app and just redirects to the webapp in that popped up window.  When I close the window the response back from authSession.startAsync is : {type: "dismiss"}. It does not get the params from the auth0 URL.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
login = async () => {
    // Retrieve the redirect URL, add this to the callback URL list
    // of your Auth0 application.
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    console.log(`Redirect URL: ${redirectUrl}`);

    // Structure the auth parameters and URL
    let authUrl =
      `${auth0Domain}/authorize` +
      toQueryString({
        client_id: auth0ClientId,
        response_type: "token",
        scope: "openid profile email",
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
      });
    console.log(`AuthURL is:  ${authUrl}`);

    // Perform the authentication
    const response: any = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: authUrl,
      returnUrl: redirectUrl,
    });
    console.log("Authentication response", response);

    if (response.type === "success") {
      this.handleResponse(response.params);
    }
  };

  handleResponse = (response: any) => {
    if (response.error) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Authentication error",
        response.error_description || "something went wrong"
      );
      return;
    }

    // Retrieve the JWT token and decode it
    const jwtToken = response.id_token;
    const decoded = jwtDecode(jwtToken);

    const name = { decoded };
    this.setState({ name });
  };
```

Comment: Same problem. Found something like this, but not sure if this helps. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6679